# YouCompleteMe plugin is not working with vim 7.4.52

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, youcompleteme

I was looking auto-completion plugin for python in vim editor. I found YCM as cool but It's not working with my editor.

when I open vim, it throw a warning as given below

```
$ vim
YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim 7.4.1578+.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

But actually, My current version of vim is 7.4.52, I don't understand why it is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, isn't the error obvious? You have 7.4.52, to work with Python YCM requires 7.4.1578+.

Comment: I think, 7.4.52 > 7.4.1578. It supposed to work @phd

Answer (score 2):

YouCompleteMe is right; your version is too old.

In Vim (as in many other applications), the third element of the version (after *major.minor*) is the *patch level*. This is a positive integer that gets incremented on each change. Here, `52` < `1578`. The `52` does **not** represent `5200`!

You can see more details in the `:version` output; it has a line with `Included patches:`